# CSS background glitch on blocks

Tags: css, background

In bottom left of my [site] I have slick slider for news ("Новость 1", "Новость 2"...) and next to third-fifth element background magically disappears. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Ohh, I found the bug myself - I need to delete `background: fixed` property! :)